# R fitting text on abline

Tags: r, plot

I want to place a text string on an fx. abline(0,0.2)

But data is changing in scale (fx. 0,01-1 and 5-2000) in my for loop, so how to control the position of the text so it always sits nicely on the abline in the plot?

(without the loop):

```
#example data row 1
x1<-1:10 
y1<-10:1

plot(x1,y1)
abline(0,0.2)
text(?,?,"text",srt=0.2)
```

Comment: This Rhelp post will do this http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/srt-slope-text-with-function-td793085.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's mine, it should scale to the slope and scale of the graph:

```
x1<-1:10 
y1<-10:1

a<-0
b<-0.2
plot(x1,y1)
abline(a,b)
text(mean(x1),(b*max(x1)/2+a),"text",srt=0.2,pos=3)
```

The argument `pos=3` denotes that the text should be offset above the point you specify, and the `x` and `y` arguments in plot are just the middle x point on the line.

**Edit**: Setting `srt=b*45` will rotate your text along the line, but mamy be fidgety for smaller scaled plots.

Comment: this proved best in my case, though the srt shold be measured in 20 and not 0.2 for it to work. Using adj rather than pos gave the best fit. This was how it ended in my script:
'text(mean(xd1[,i]), b1 * max(xd1[,i]/2) + a, "<10%",adj=c(0,5))'
'text(mean(xd1[,i]), b1 * max(xd1[,i]/2) + a, "10-20%", srt=10,adj=c(0,0))'
'text(mean(xd1[,i]), b2 * max(xd1[,i]/2) + a, ">20%",srt=20)'

Comment: AFAIK `srt=0.2` is in degrees, and thus that `0.2` seems unrelated to `b` being `0.2`. Thus a formula is actually needed instead of `srt=0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick one (enhanced with color):

```
x1<-1:10 
y1<-10:1
plot(x1,y1)
a <- 0
b <- .2
abline(a,b, col = "blue")
text(mean(x1), b * max(x1) + a, "text", srt=0.2, col = "blue")
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `text(mean(x1), b * mean(x1) + a, "text", srt=atan(b)/(2*pi)*360, pos=3, col = "blue")`?